# Why does PuLP call copy for addition and how can I avoid it?

Tags: modeling, pulp

Using a for loop to append terms to an expression seems to be much faster than summing a group of terms all at once.  Constructing the expression using a for loop uses __iadd__, which does not include a call to copy.  The other methods of building the expression result in many calls to __add__ which does call copy and is quite slow.

Of the six methods below, "using_loop" is arguably the most difficult to read, but is by far the fastest.

Is there a best practice method of building large constraints which is both readable and avoids the call to __add__ (and copy) in pulp? If I edit the __add__ function in pulp to remove the copy, are there side effects I should anticipate?

```
import pulp
import numpy as np


def using_np_mat_mul(X, coef):
    x2d = np.atleast_2d(np.array(X))
    coef2d = np.atleast_2d(np.array(coef)).T
    expr = np.matmul(x2d, coef2d)
    return expr


def using_loop(X, coef):
    expr = 0
    for i in range(len(X)):
        expr += X[i]*coef[i]
    return expr


def using_sum_of_list(X, coef):
    expr = sum([X[i]*coef[i] for i in range(len(X))])
    return expr

def using_sum_mult(X, coef):
    expr = sum(np.array(X)*np.array(coef))
    return expr


def using_lpsum(X, coef):
    expr = pulp.lpSum(X[i]*coef[i] for i in range(len(X)))
    return expr

def using_dict_and_lpsum(X_dict, coef):
    expr = pulp.lpSum(X_dict[i]*coef[i] for i in X_dict.keys())
    return expr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nx = 5000

    X = [pulp.LpVariable(str(i)) for i in range(nx)]

    coef = np.random.rand(nx)

    e1 = using_np_mat_mul(X, coef)
    e2 = using_loop(X, coef)
    e3 = using_sum_of_list(X, coef)
    e4 = using_sum_mult(X, coef)
    e5 = using_lpsum(X, coef)

    # create an expression = X * coef
    X_dict = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('', range(nx))
    e6 = using_dict_and_lpsum(X_dict, coef)
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a `PuLP` question or a `numpy` question? (Would the same issue arise if `X` were not derived from `PuLP` variables?) If it's general `numpy`, you should ask on [so] instead. If it's specific to `PuLP`, then it's welcome here.

Comment: Since you're timing, I suggest to test another version: `expr = pulp.lpSum(X[i]*coef[i] for i in range(len(X)))`. Also, check to see the effect if you create your variable `X` using `pulp.LpVariable.dicts()` method.

Comment: @EhsanK, thank you!  Added.  It has similar performance to the loop, but is much easier to read.